# Ask Facebook Permissions without LoginButton

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get Facebook permission with this basic code :

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.d("call", "Called : " + state.toString());
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            Log.d("session.isOpened()", "Called");
            // make request to the /me API

            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.d("onCompleted", "Called");
                    if (user != null) {
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Just show me please, with this code, how to add permissions.

I saw this code:

```
private static Session
openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean allowLoginUI, StatusCallback callback, List<String> permissions)
{
    Log.d("openActiveSession","called");
    OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(activity).setPermissions(permissions).setCallback(callback);
    Session session = new Builder(activity).build();
    if (SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED.equals(session.getState()) || allowLoginUI) {
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        session.openForRead(openRequest);
        return session;
    }
    return null;
}
```

but I dont know if this is the most simple way, or how and when to implement it.

Comment: What do you mean by "Add permissions"? Permissions are set on Token Request ("scope") and can not be changed afterwards?

Comment: i want to receive user's frinds list and page he liked .

Comment: Fine. Look for the "scope" Parameter in the OAuth request and set the access rights accordingly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions

Comment: i dont use button and fragment .thats why i have problem

Comment: You need to be granted by a user to read his data. No other way.